# Installing R Packages with dependencies

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, r, rstudio

I have recently made the move from Windows to Ubuntu (actually for the 2nd time, but I think this time it is for real!), and I have managed to install R and RStudio.

When, in RStudio, I run the line

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

I get a whole bunch of errors, including

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘git2r’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/home/travis/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/devtools’
```

When I install packages in Windows as above, it always installs all dependencies at the same time.

How do I fix this and what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. Apparently I need to run

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the `SystemRequirements` field of an R package's DESCRIPTION file will tell you what additonal dependencies you will need to install.

In the case of `devtools`, you should have seen some errors when installing some of its depnedencies (*e.g.* `curl`). Taking a look at [`curl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html), it tells us it needs `libcurl`:

> SystemRequirements:   libcurl: libcurl-devel (rpm) or libcurl4-openssl-dev (deb).

and tells us which deb package to install to get it.